# How to create reports in ArcGIS using Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, reports

Does anyone have experience in creating reports from your ArcGIS data (geodatabase, map exports) using a python reporting engine? In my current project, we are using Jasper Reports in the following way: A custom geoprocessing tool creates a intermediate XML file containing the data from the Oracle SDE and an exported map image as encoded byte array. This file and a template from iReport is used to generate a PDF file by Jasper Reports.

I am looking for a different solution using a report engine based on python (Jasper is based on Java), I can imagine that a python approach can be better integrated in ArcGIS.

Did anyone tried this before?

Comment: What type of text data is in your report (attribute table based)?

Comment: Yes, attribute tables of feature classes in a geodatabase for example. But it should not be restricted to that kind of data. A "screenshot" of the map should also be exported, by arcmap or may be by a map service.

Comment: How do I want to generate the similar report on a web based application?

Comment: That would be another question. JasperReports can be used for reporting in a web based application, either by writing a Java Servlet or using the server of JasperSoft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the 2012 ESRI User conference, they demonstrated building custom PDF pages and reports using the [open-souce ReportLab toolkit](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/).

Check out the [Conference proceedings](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc12/) and look at the Technical Workshops for Python Map Automation.  One of them makes a reference to [this sample script](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0588e23e83f245afaa8501e84e7b25e5).

Answer (score 5):

There is a new development in 10.1 for Python access in reporting: [ExportReport](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004v00000022000000).

Essentially you create a report and save the layout as a report layout file (.rlf).  When you call ExportReport from arcpy you access the layout file.

Comment: In case anyone is looking at this answer with web applications in mind, you should be aware that: the ExportReport function has a dependency on the ArcMap installation. Therefore, ExportReport can only be executed on machines that have ArcMap installed. ExportReport will not run using stand-alone installations of ArcGIS Engine or ArcGIS for Server. Moreover, ExportReport will not work as a Geoprocessing Service.  Source: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exportreport.htm#D_GUID-79B935E6-64B9-4346-942E-BBD77E4EEC4C